# Distribution file source is different to development path source

Tags: html, image, npm, gulp

I've started using a task runner to export all of my folders into a distribution folder using Gulp. The problem arises when I export images into the distribution folder, the path name is different from the one I'm using in my src file. So, as an example, when I target an image in HTML I type:

/assets/images/example.jpg

However, when the HTML file is distributed, it is supposed to target:

/images/example.jpg

It's still pointing to the assets folder, and creates a dead link. Should I be using a module like gulp-replace to automatically change these path names? Or should I just type in the assumed path name? Or, is there another method that I'm missing?

Sorry if I've phrased this badly, I'm working towards a new developer environment - let me know if I can provide you with any other details.

Comment: You could simply replicate your _src_ subfolders to your _dist_ folder so you have the following folder structure _dist>assets>images>example.jpg_.  Or vice versa, if `/images/example.jpg` is the path reference you'd prefer to use in your distributed code, then remove the _assets_ folder from your _src_ so you have the following folder structure _src>images>example.jpg_. Either way the relative path references then do not need to change between your source code and distribution code.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be using a module like gulp-replace to automatically change
>   these path names?

Yes, [gulp-replace](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiYr-qQk_TRAhViEJoKHdz2CigQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.npmjs.com%2Fpackage%2Fgulp-replace&usg=AFQjCNHn298EZRwsLq3nnoTtvHAFusrvFA&sig2=4JSfrnQqslAvG526sBfEyQ) will do the trick.

As an alternative you can place your index.html file into assets folder, so you don't need to change any paths when distributing the project.

Comment: I think keeping the file structures together might actually make more sense for the purpose of legibility and structure - thanks for the help.

Comment: @JCoulam - you're right. I think the alternative as suggested should be what you try to achieve first. If for any reason you can't achieve that then the alternative would be to use yet another dependency such as [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace).